# Filter csvlines before inserting the values in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the LOAD CSV inside cypher to populate my database. I would like to skip lines with blank values in specific field before creating the node in neo4j.

I've tried something like:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/..../file.csv" AS csvline

MATCH csvline WHERE csvline.name <>""

WITH csvline
MERGE (n {name: csvline.name})
```

but I get the following error
"Cannot match on a pattern containing only already bound identifiers"

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Neo4j 2.1.2 by any chance? I bumped into this error message yesterday.

Try:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/..../file.csv" AS csvline
WITH csvline
WHERE csvline.name <>""
MERGE ({name: csvline.name});
```

(Notice you don't need the `n` identifier since you never use it.)

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works!! Sorry, I've forgot to mention that I'm using version 2.1.2.